# Updating class in jar, specify directory?

Tags: java, jar

I want to update a .class file in a jar.  The .class file is in a folder in the jar.  If I want to update it, do I need to specify the specific pathname where it's located?

Do I do:
        jar uf myJar.jar myFolder/myClass.class

or just:
        jar uf myJar.jar myClass.class

If I don't specify path, will it automatically find the .class and replace it?  Or are jars allowed to have the same .class names within different directories?

Comment: why do you want to update class file in a jar ? you need to update your code and then create your jar file again which will have updated version of you .class file

Comment: @CPU100 I only have the jar, not any of the .java files.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, and you know that only one class has changed, then it's perfectly valid. Note that you should bewar eof modifying a class such that it has inner classes, in which case you'd need to remove the old class and insert the new class *plus* the inner classes

Comment: @user2019538 use a decompiler http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ to get the code and rebuild you application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be explicit. It's perfectly valid to have different classes with the same name in different packages. e.g.

```
com.example.package.A
com.example.package.subpackage.A
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full path name to update the jar file

jar uf myJar.jar myFolder/myClass.class

And you can have same class files in different directories

Answer (score 0):

jar uf jar-file input 
-> as you want to update a file which is already existent you have to specify the folder structure.