# Changes in a jar file made using 'jar uf ...' are not picked up

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I tried to make slight changes in a class and replace it in a .jar file. I don't have the sources for most of the classes in the .jar, though the developer kindly provided me with the code of the class I'm interested in.

I created a project, compiled the modified class, carefully keeping the original class and package name, then copied the resulting .class file under the directory where the target .jar resides. I kept the directory structure intact as well, like this:

```
cd {the directory of the target .jar}
mkdir com\{company name}\{package name}
copy {full path to my .class file} com\{company name}\{package name}
jar uf {target .jar} com\{company name}\{package name}\{class name}.class
```

When I do 'jar tvf' on the file, I notice the change in the date of the class I worked on - but when I restart the application which is using the jar, the changes (I made some modifications in log messages for easy detection) are not working.

I looked at this:
[Updating class in jar, specify directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215007/updating-class-in-jar-specify-directory)
but realized that I'm already doing what it suggests. What are other ways of checking whether I'm doing it right? (Or rather *what I'm doing wrong*) I'm using Spring Tool Suite at work, so any actions using Eclipse are fine :)

Comment: If the timestamp and file size of the class within the jar match the new version, then I'd be inclined to think you're updating the jar correctly. In that case, if the old copy of the class is still being used, then there must be another copy of it somewhere.

Comment: Absolutely - that's my train of thought as well. I just wasn't sure if there are any additional conditions such as version number, etc.